# Can I make details with Metaball?

Tags: modeling

I try to model a mouse with metaball. I don't know if it is the best tool for modeling. [image]

The structure is too solid. Can I make details? I don't know how to make the fingers.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, you can always convert meta to mesh (ALT + C), after getting a good overall shape... and then, add details in other ways.

Comment: If the mouse is supposed to be an embossed ornament, you can finish up using the sculpt tools. If this will be a character to be viewed from multiple angles it may be easier to start over with a quad mesh - or shrinkwrap a quad mesh over the sculpt. If this mouse will need to be animated or put in other poses, it would be best to create a symmetrical model that looks how you imagine the mouse would look if viewed straight-on, and then rig/pose it. So depending on your end goal, the best approach may vary.